# How are random walk entry transactions chosen in a coo-free tangle?

Tags: tip-selection, coordinator, milestones

With the coordinator, the MCMC random walk tip selection algorithm starts with a milestone as its entry transaction. Without the coordinator, there are no milestones. How is the entry transaction for the random walk chosen in this case?

Comment: If I interpret https://github.com/iotaledger/cliri/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/service/tipselection/impl/EntryPointSelectorCumulativeWeightThreshold.java correctly, it starts from a random tip and then walks randomly backwards until it hits some cumulative weight. No idea how practical/bugfree the current implementation is, considering it is only 3 days old...

Comment: @TheCoordinator a transaction is a solid tip when : it is not yet approved by another transaction, and it's branch and trunk are solid. A transaction is solid when all it's ancestors are  known (i.e. in the local DB)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87208/discussion-on-question-by-wass-how-are-random-walk-entry-transactions-chosen-in).